# servicestack ormlite throws "The ORDER BY clause is invalid ..." sql exception when using orderby with References

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have models like:

```
class Request
{
   public int RequestId {get;set;}
   [Reference]
   public List<Package> Packages {get;set;}
}

class Package 
{
   public int PackageId {get;set;}
   public inst RequestId {get;set;}
}
```

if I run:

```
db.LoadSelect<Request>(q => q.OrderBy(x => x.RequestId));
```

OrmLite will generate sqls like:

```
SELECT "RequestId"  FROM "Request" ORDER BY "RequestId" ASC

SELECT "PackageId", "RequestId" FROM "Package"
WHERE "RequestId" IN (SELECT "Request"."RequestId" FROM "Request" ORDER BY "RequestId" ASC)
```

which will raise the following sql error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR
>   XML is also specified.

and the reason is obviously the ORDER BY in the subquery of the second query.

So there are two points here:

1. Is this a bug in OrmLite Sql Provider?
2. How to write ormlite queries to load models with references and at the same time sort them?

Comment: What does `LoadSelect` do?

Comment: @DavidG, `LoadSelect` queries pocos with references https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#querying-pocos-with-references

Comment: Those examples look like they take a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` but what you posted above doesn't?

Comment: OrderBy signature is `SqlExpression<T> OrderBy(Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector)`. The example in the link does not have orderby. It is just a basic filtering which should be ` Expression<Func<T, bool>>` as you said. But I am not filtering. I am sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, not being able to use `ORDER BY` in Sub Selects seems to be an Sql Server specific limitation. But as it shouldn't affect the behavior, I've cleared the `ORDER BY` term used in Load References sub selects [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/8d328f484585d96af94e0cc9c32768f854f1898e).

This change is available from **v4.0.33+** that's [now available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Will that solution worth if the LoadSelect also has paging?  In that case you want the sub select to preserve ordering so you are loading the right set of reference data.

Comment: @jklemmack the subquery is only used for the IN sub select (where ordering has no effect), the ORDER BY on the main query still remains.

Comment: But if you're doing a paged query, or just anything with either 'TOP' or 'LIMIT', the ORDER BY its necessary.  When i played with this, i checked whether there was a TOP clause and set to be TOP 100 PERCENT if it wasn't set (or technically if it matched Int32.Max).  That covers either case, if there is an order by our not.  Only tested on MSSQL.

Comment: @jklemmack How did you test it if MSSQL doesn't support ORDER BY in subselects? Can you [submit a new issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues) that shows what you mean?

Comment: FYI, SQL Server DOES support ORDER BY in subselects, so long as there is a TOP clause.  Using TOP 100 PERCENT is a bit of a hack if there isn't a "take" parameter, but doesn't show any notable performance difference.